# What is different between "import<ABC/ABC.h>" and "import<ABC.h>"

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I studied other people's iOS open source code, I found that some programmers prefer to import third-party frameworks like this `import<ABC/ABC.h>`, but there are some use `import<ABC.h>`.

I want to know What is different between `import<ABC/ABC.h>` and `import<ABC.h>`?

Is it because of `import<ABC/ABC.h>` would be faster?

Comment: Did you mean the difference between `import ABC.h` and `import <ABC/ABC.h>`?

Comment: @Godric I use CocoaPod import some thrid-framework,When I want use it, The Xcode hinted me use <ABC/ABC.h> or <ABC.h> .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import<ABC/ABC.h>` imports ABC.h from folder ABC in your project. And `import<ABC.h>` is directly imported because this file is directly referenced in your project folder while the other one is in a folder and then can't be reference directly. Note: Groups and folders are different things in Xcode.

Comment: Just for clarification: Groups are the little folder icons you see in the project navigator in the left pane in Xcode, folders refer to the location of the file in the file system (in the Finder). You can see the path where the file is located by selecting it in the project navigator and have the attribute inspector in the right pane open.